# Express-session with react not working, Getting null in the session what to do?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, session-cookies, express-session

I want to create a react app , in the login system after login I save the email to session. But on the next request the saved data getting null here is my code,

Express cors section

```
  app.use(cors({
  
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials:true,       
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
    optionSuccessStatus:200,
}))
  // Router setup middlewares
  app.options('http://localhost:3000', cors())
```

Express login section

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  superAdminHelpers
    .Login(req.body.body)
    .then((response) => {
      req.session.superAdmin = response.email;
      res.send(response);
   
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(401).send(err);
    });
});
```

Getting the response email correctly

React request

```
   axios
    .post(LoginURL, {
      body: loginDetails,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      withCredentials: true
      
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What was happening is that every time I used axios to call other api after logging in, a new session was being created every new request. The way I solved it is:

> In the fronend:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const request = axios.create({
  baseURL:   process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BACKENDURL,
  timeout: 20000,
  withCredentials: true,
});




export default request
```

Create an axios instance. By doing so, the previous session that you used for logging in will be preserved. Import this instance and use it in every api requests instead of create new instances.

> For backend:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION') {
    let sess = {
        secret: '',
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: false,
        proxy: true,
        name:"app",
        cookie: {
            secure: true, // This will only work if you have https enabled!
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: 'none'
        }
    };

    app.use(session(sess));
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEVELOPMENT') {
    let sess = {
        secret: '',
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: false,
        proxy: true,
        name:"app",
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
        }
    };

    app.use(session(sess));
};
```